# Authorization through certificate (SSL)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirect

There is a problem.

The server contains the certificate (*.crt). And there are two different users. One is set in the browser certificate (*.p12), which signed the server certificate. The user enters the folder **example.com/a**

A user who doesn't have a certificate enters **example.com/b**

How to do it using the settings apache? Redirect?

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're asking here.  Can you rephrase it, preferably with a table of the URLs, expected results and actual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use mod_rewrite for this. I've not tested the config below, but it's a place for you to start from...

In the SSL settings, you use

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
```

This means that you will allow clients to use authentication if they are able to, but you'll allow them to connect even if they can't. In order for this to work, you also need to trust the CA that has issued the client certificate; this is done by adding

```
SSLCACertificateFile path/to/file
```

to your config and having the certificate for the CA in that file.

Then, you use mod_rewrite to check for an environment variable that gets set by a client with a certificate you approve:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond   %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} SUCCESS
 RewriteRule   ^/(.*) /a/(.*) [L]

 RewriteCond   %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} FAILED
 RewriteRule   ^/(.*) /b/(.*) [L]
```